# Androidアプリ内課金(IABv3)でGooglePlayサーバからskuを取得する方法

Tags: android, アプリ内課金

Androidアプリ内課金(IABv3)でGooglePlayサーバからskuを取得する方法

getSkuDetailsのサンプルなどで、skuをハードコーディング
しているのをよく見かけます。

```
ArrayList<String> skuList = new ArrayList<String>();  
skuList.add("premiumUpgrade");  
skuList.add("gas");  
Bundle querySkus = new Bundle();  
querySkus.putStringArrayList("ITEM_ID_LIST", skuList);
```

しかしこのままだと新規アイテムを追加したら、その都度addする必要があります。

そこで、Google Play Developer Consoleに登録されている全アプリ内アイテムのskuを
GooglePlayサーバから動的に取得する。

そんな方法を探しているのですが、ありますでしょうか？